# Changing www to point to non-www, instead of the opposite, using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm switching servers and need to change the following *RewriteCond* and *RewriteRule* commands in the *.htaccess* file.

Right now I'm pointing `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

I need to switch the commands and do the opposite, where I point `www.domain.com` to `domain.com`.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change the URL structure in the same two lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: you need to escape your www.domain.com to www\.domain\.com and with the one below. Still a simple nice answer

Comment: Thanks. It's only suggested to escape metacharacters in the _regular expressions_ of a RewriteRule, but not the target. See `Regular Expressions` [here](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).

Comment: I was unaware of that, thank you for the correction